# Unable to set remote file time for FTP file transfer

Tags: server, ftp, file-transfer

I am running into this issue when trying to transfer some files from my local C drive to an external company's server.

It appears as if all the files are transferred, each FTP client I have tried returns messages indicating the files were successfully transferred, but then when you go to the directory on the server there are no files.

I have tried using WinSCP as well as FTPVoyager, both with very similar results. I'm trying to automate this transfer but I have also tried to just manually drag the files over in the GUI, which also doesn't work.

WinSCP doesn't return any errors, but it doesn't transfer the files even though it says it does.

FTP Voyager returns the error "Unable to set remote file time for 'FILE'" for each file. But the funny thing is that it also says the files were successfully transferred, even though they were not.

I have no idea what "Unable to set remote file time" could mean, other than maybe it doesn't have permission from the server to change the file time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the script and batch files I was using for WinSCP:

script:

```
open ftp://username:password@host.net/
lcd C:\EDI_CMG_ERP\Output
cd /ns/ftp/receiveFF
ASCII
put *
exit
```

batch:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\@Databases\EDI\CMG_FTP\Logs\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@host.net/" ^
    "lcd C:\EDI_CMG_ERP\Output" ^
    "cd /ns/ftp/receiveFF" ^
    "ASCII" ^
    "put *" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

(FTPVoyager doesn't require these files)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any reason to believe the file should be visible in the remote directory after you upload them?

It looks like your server either:

- is configured not to reveal the files to clients; or
- immediately moves uploaded files elsewhere; or
- immediately processes and deleted uploaded files; or
- similar.

Comment: I should be able to see the files in the remote directory, and you can see them briefly after the file transfer if you use the GUI in an FTP client or a File explorer to make the transfer. The problem is once you refresh the remote directory the files disappear.

Comment: OK, so maybe the server does not move the files "immediately", but after some short processing. It does not invalidate my answer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl If one can see the files in the remote directory using the GUI, shouldn't one be able to see the files in the remote directory using script and batch? Surely this has no effect on the processing speed of the remote directory, so how do you account for the difference in behavior? I am interested, as this behavior seems unexpected to me. Especially since OP is claiming that it occurs across various FTP clients, but not in GUI. It does sound possible that the files could be failing to send, and thus far your answer hasn't ruled out that possibility, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Joshu'sMu I can answer that if the OP posts a log file both from GUI and scripting. + The behavior the OP is experiencing suggests that file was sent. There's no failure reported.